# CSS width 100% cuts off on minimized window

Tags: html, css

I have a website with the header bar colour width as 100%, but when it is bordered to the left of the screen, it cuts it off when I scroll across?

Here is an example:

[image: full width works fine]

But if it is a smaller window and scrolled across:

[image: scrollbar]

How can I get the width to be 100% when the screen is halved like in the picture?

Sorry for the bad explanation, I don't know how to explain it well. Hopefully the pictures will help.

My css is:

```
Header{background-color: #58dede; width: 100%;}
```

Comment: more code is needed to answer your question otherwise we will be guessing and there are many many possible issues. post your html code too please

Comment: Is horizontal scrolling necessary? If not try `body { overflow-x:hidden; }`

Comment: Try giving the Header max-width:100%;

Comment: Tried that, still having the same issue.

Comment: @DamianFrizzi I need horizontal scrolling, so I cannot so that

Answer (score 1):

Although, its difficult to imagine your issue but you can try this code -

CSS:

```
Header{background-color: #58dede; /*width: 100%;*/ float:none !important; }
.clear {clear:both;}
```

HTML:

```
<header>
your content
<div class="clear"></div>
</header>
```

Comment: Still same issue, there is still that white space

Comment: what do you mean by " but when it is bordered to the left of the screen". please help me to understand your issue.

Comment: When you drag the window to the left or right of the screen and it sticks to half the screen

Comment: can you check in firebug if header is taking float:left or display:block from somewhere..? or try adding float:none in your header css as i edited in my answer.

Comment: It's not giving me float:left from anywhere

Answer (score 0):

You have set the width of your header to 100% and after downsizing your browser width, the width of your header is cut down to 100% of your viewport width instead of staying the same width as the html and/or header content. So when you are presented with a horizontal scroll bar and then scroll to the right, the background colour is no longer applying to the entire desired width of your header because your header is no longer that width.

This can be easily fixed by adjusting the

```
min-width: property
```

to the width of all your combined margins + element widths (assuming box-sizing: border-box has been set, thus including padding and margin into your width). If you have used percentages in your margins or for child divs of your header, just include those within a calc () function for the property value of min-width.

```
min-width: calc(2% + 200px + ...); etc
```

Answer (score 0):

The body content of your HTML is having a fixed width even though you give it 100% width because of its inner elements. So, if the horizontal scroll content has a fixed length below is fix. Assume horizontal scroll content is z px long (which is fixed).

```
.header{
  min-width : zpx;
}
```

I had same problem in one of my applications which I fixed this way

Answer (score -1):

In your body tag mention minimum document width for your page. For instance:

```
body{min-width:1000px;}
```